# Speeding up perfect swap calculation - avoiding loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```py
import sys

t=(int(sys.stdin.readline()))

for i in range(0,t):
    n=int(sys.stdin.readline())
    c=0
    s=n*(n+1)/2
    if s%2!=0:
        print(0)
    else:
        c=0
        i=-1
        a=[i for i in range(1,n+1)]
        h=s//2
        m=0
        s1=0
        for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
            s1+=a[i]
            c+=1
            if s1==h:
                m=1
                break
            if s1>h:
                break
        if m==1:
            s1=((c+1)*(2+((c-1)-1)))//2+((n-c-1)*(2+((n-c-1)-1)))//2
            print(s1)
        else:
            print(c)
```

I am new to python , How can i write this code with using for loop? i don't want to use for loop because i get TLE error. Thanks in advance

Here is the question :

N. Consider the sequence sequence=(1,2,…,N). You should choose two elements of this sequence and swap them.

A swap is perfect if there is an integer o (1≤o<N) such that the sum of the first M elements of the resulting sequence is equal to the sum of its last N−o elements. Find the number of perfect swaps.

Comment: what is TLE? what should your code do? can you simplify the code to the bare minimum that is necessary? (e.g. there is no point for `n=int(sys.stdin.readline())` here...). i count 3 for loops. do you want to get rid of them all? and most importantly: why?

Comment: If you are getting a "Time limit exceeded" error, (I suppose that is what TLE means?) then you want to make your program more efficient. You will not become more efficient by not using a for loop if what you want to do requires repetition. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist bro TLE is time limit exceed error . so to get rid of that i dont't want any for loop in the given code so my question is how i can write the same code without using any for loop?

Comment: if you want ideas on how to speed up your code you might want to add the problem you want to solve...

Comment: it doesn't show me any TLE error. What input did you use, i think we need more information.

Comment: @jairoar Hey bro the range of input N is 10^9.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist just added the question.

Answer (score 0):

i got interested in the problem and found this so far:

a slow version that creates list and really does swap elements is this:

```
from itertools import combinations

def slow(N):

    found = 0
    for i, j in combinations(range(N), 2):

        lst = list(range(1, N + 1))
        lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]

        for m in range(1, N):
            a = m * (m + 1) // 2
            b = (N - m) * (N + m + 1) // 2
            if i < m <= j:
                a = a - i + j
                b = b - j + i

            assert a == sum(lst[:m])
            assert b == sum(lst[m:])

            if sum(lst[:m]) == sum(lst[m:]):
                found += 1

                if i < m <= j:
                    assert 2 * m * (m + 1) + 4 * j == N * (N + 1) + 4 * i
                else:
                    assert 2 * m * (m + 1) == N * (N + 1)

            else:
                if i < m <= j:
                    assert 2 * m * (m + 1) + 4 * j != N * (N + 1) + 4 * i
                else:
                    assert 2 * m * (m + 1) != N * (N + 1)
    return found
```

as you see i found criteria the indices have to fulfill in order for the sum to be correct:

```
if i < m <= j:
    assert 2 * m * (m + 1) + 4 * j == N * (N + 1) + 4 * i
else:
    assert 2 * m * (m + 1) == N * (N + 1)
```

i also found the direct formula to calculate the sum up to `m` and the one starting from `m`:

```
a = m * (m + 1) // 2
b = (N - m) * (N + m + 1) // 2
if i < m <= j:
    a = a - i + j
    b = b - j + i
```

all of that can can be calculated using some basic mathematics.

---

starting from that you can do some more maths and see that there are 2 cases to consider:

1. there is an `m` such that the sum of the original list `[1, 2, 3, ..., m, m+1, ..., N]` up to `m` equals the sum of the rest of the list (e.g. `N = 20; m = 14`). two cases again:

   1. all the swaps that do not cross the `m` boundary are valid (there are `comb(m, 2) + comb((N - m), 2)`) of them.
   2. when you split at `m-1` you will find more swaps; this time you have to swap accross the `m-1` boundary.

   the `m` in that case is calculated from

   ```
   m = - 1 + sqrt(1 + 2 * N * (N + 1)) / 2
   ```
2. the calculation for `m` in the first case is not an integer (i.e. `1 + 2 * N * (N + 1)` is not a perfect square). the `m` to consider is then then the [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of the result of the formula above (i use `int` instead of `math.floor`). two cases again for the `diff`erence of the sum of the two splits:

   1. the difference is even: there are more swaps that need to go over the `m` boundary.
   2. the difference is odd: no additional swaps (swapping will always result in an even difference)

this is the code:

```
from math import sqrt, comb

def fast(N):
    found = 0

    arg = (1 + 2 * N * (N + 1))
    sq = round(sqrt(arg))
    if sq ** 2 == arg and sq & 1:
        m = (-1 + sq) // 2
        found += comb(m, 2) + comb((N - m), 2)

        m -= 1
        found += N - m - 1
    else:
        m = int((-1 + sqrt(arg)) // 2)
        diff = ((m + 1 + N) * (N - m) - m * (m + 1)) // 2
        if diff & 1 == 0:
            found += N - m

    return found
```

Comment: Thank u bro. upvote for your efforts . and i'll try to complete the rest incomplete part great. thank you again.

Comment: @Akashnitter do you have the results for some `N` so i could verify what i really need to count?

Comment: n- 3 output -2 , n4 output -2 input 7 , output-3 , n-20 output -112